# Use all cores when tar and splitting

Tags: linux, multithreading, split, compression, tar

I'm trying to make my tar command to use all cores (8), I got it working when I pack into a single pack like this: `tar -I pigz -cf packed.tar.gz folder/`.
It is working as it should, it uses all cores.

But when I need to pack into multiply files I can't get it to use all cores, this is my command: `tar cvzf - folder/ | split --bytes=4GB - packed.tar.gz`.
How can I make this command to use all cores and not only one?

Thanks for all inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With multithreaded file compression tool pigz:

```
tar -I pigz -cvf - folder/ | split --bytes=4GB - packed.tar.gz
```